# How I should write this SQL

Tags: sql, relational-database, firebird

Using Firebird 3.0 I have these tables

[image]

The model_types table has some types like Type1, type2, type3... and I need get a result like this:

```
Type     All    UFZ   Tempered
=================================
Type1     45     23      12
Type2     0      0       0
Type3     2      0       0
```

So I wrote this SQL:

```
select 
    sum((window.win_width * window.win_height) / 144),
    model_types.model_type_description
from model_types
   left outer join models on (model_types.model_type_id = models.model_type_id)
   inner join series_model on (models.model_id = series_model.model_id)
   inner join window on (series_model.sm_id = window.sm_id)
 where (quote_id = 122) and (window.ufz = 0) and (window.tempered = 0)
 group by model_types.model_type_description
```

The problem this SQL give me only "type1" if other types are zeros so how I list all types from model_types table even if they are zeros ?

Another question: in this SQL the where condition :

```
(window.ufz = 0) and (window.tempered = 0)
```

represent the "All" column while to get UFZ I need to use these conditions:

```
(window.ufz = 1) and (window.tempered = 0)
```

and to get Tempered I need to use this conditions:

```
(window.ufz = 0) and (window.tempered = 1)
```

So how I display all the 3 results (All, UFZ, Tempered) each one in separate column ?

Answer (score 0):

After many testing I found that I can use `Case` but dont know if my SQL is correct or not also it does not display all model types if they are zeros.

```
select 
    sum(CASE WHEN (window.ufz = 0) and (window.tempered = 0)
      THEN ((window.win_width * window.win_height) / 144) END) AS models_all,

    sum(CASE WHEN (window.ufz = 1) and (window.tempered = 0)
      THEN ((window.win_width * window.win_height) / 144) END) AS models_ufz,

    sum(CASE WHEN (window.ufz = 0) and (window.tempered = 1)
      THEN ((window.win_width * window.win_height) / 144) END) AS models_temp,

    model_types.model_type_description
from model_types
   left outer join models on (model_types.model_type_id = models.model_type_id)
   inner join series_model on (models.model_id = series_model.model_id)
   inner join window on (series_model.sm_id = window.sm_id)
 where (quote_id = 122)
 group by model_types.model_type_description
```

Comment: If you want **all**, then you shouldn't use a restriction like `(window.ufz = 0) and (window.tempered = 0)`, because that restricts to windows that are not ufz nor tempered. I also wonder if you want to exclude windows that are ufz **and** tempered from your 'models_ufz' and 'models_temp' counts. You might want to consider posting example data for all tables involved. Also note that the `left outer join` in your query is implicitly transformed to an inner join by your use of `window.ufz = ...` and `window.tempered = ...`.

Comment: how to avoid turn left outer join to an inner join ? I dont use window.ufz and window.tempered in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

The CASE construct has an ELSE part where you may add a default value for the case that your WHEN part is not validated. I think this will complete the missing data of your query result.